# Event is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a event that's triggered when the number value changes in the `<input type="number">` one below:

```
<input type="number" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" size="4" class="lorem"  value="0" step="1">
<input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
<input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
```

It works fine.

However, I have plus/minus buttons below it. These buttons increase/decrease the value but when that happens, the event is never triggered. Why?

How can I make it so that the event is triggered?

Comment: What event ? Where's the code ? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post your `javascript`. HTML alone isn't going to solve this for you.

Comment: Why? Beacuse [`onchange`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-changev) is "_Fired at controls when the user commits a value change_". JavaScript is not a user.

Comment: Who upvoted this?!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need below code for update value in input box by clicking on plus and minus button.

```js
$(".minus,.plus").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).val()=="-")
  {
   var incr=-1;  
  }
  else
  {
    var incr=1;
  }
  $(".lorem").val(parseInt($(".lorem").val())+incr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" size="4" class="lorem"  value="0" step="1">
<input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
<input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
```

Answer (score 0):

After you change a value with plus/minus buttons, you need to fire a *change* event on that numeric field. It would look something like this:

```
$(".minus").click(function() {
  var $numberField = $("input[type=number]");
  // Assign a new value to the field and fire change event
  $numberField.val("1").change();
})
```

If you need some more help, please upload your JavaScript code.